# Nesting a CAST() Function

Tags: sql, casting, nested, intersystems-cache

I am attempting create a nested CAST() function and am struggling with the syntax. My simplified code so far:

```
SELECT 
discharge_date,
admission_date,
Patient_Uniue_ID,
CAST(CAST(Year(admission_date) AS VarChar(4)) + '-' + CAST(Month(admission_date) AS VarChar(2)) + '-' + CAST(Day(admission_date) AS VarChar(2)) AS DATE) AS 'Due_Date'

FROM   SYSTEM.client_history

WHERE DateDiff('d',Due_Date, GetDate()) <= 14
```

Trying to get the casted due date to be set yearly on the anniversary of admission, but I get an "invalid SQL format" and "Option expected, IDENTIFIER(DATEFORMAT)" error. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Is `admission_date` a `Date` or `DateTime` or `DateTime2` or something similar? If so use built in date methods/functions/operators (what you use depends on the RDBMS you are using). For example: In Sql Server you can use DateAdd if you want to increment the date by something (like 1 year for example).

Comment: admission_date is a date, and I am attempting to capture the Month and Day, since due dates are set yearly on the date of admission. The idea is to have the clients pop up when their "Due Date" is within 14 days of today. I cannot simply use a dateadd because the due date is recurring each year.

Comment: I would use `DATEFROMPARTS` with the current year and the month and day from the `admission_date`. Then you can compare that to GetDate() using DateDiff and check if it is between 14 and 0.

Comment: Also the WHERE clause does not take items you construct in the SELECT clause, you have to use the DATEFROMPARTS in the where clause unless you are using a nested query.

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: I use a specialized version of Intersystems unstructured, cache database.

Comment: Thank you @Igor. The system has limited SQL functioning, so DATEFROMPARTS is not accepted- dang!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might do the trick.

There are two redundant columns in the query below that show my workings to get the anniverary date for both this year and next year.  Both add the difference between the current year and the admission year, with an extra year added to get next year.

I'm using the same calculated dates within a CASE statement.  If the anniversary date for this year is less than '14 days in the future' then the anniversary is next year date.  Otherwise it is this year.

```js
select admission_date
, CAST (DateAdd('yyyy', (Year(GETDATE())-Year(admission_Date)),admission_date) as DATE) as 'admission_date_THIS_YEAR'
, CAST (DateAdd('yyyy', (Year(GETDATE())-Year(admission_Date)+1),admission_date) as DATE) as 'admission_date_NEXT_YEAR'
, CAST (CASE WHEN (DateAdd('yyyy', (Year(GETDATE())-Year(admission_date)),admission_date)
                   < DateAdd('dd',14,GETDATE()))
             THEN DateAdd('yyyy', (Year(GETDATE())-Year(admission_date)+1),admission_date)
             ELSE DateAdd('yyyy', (Year(GETDATE())-Year(admission_date)),admission_date)
  END as DATE) As 'Admission_Anniversary'
FROM SYSTEM.client_history
```

You might not need the `CAST (... as DATE)` but it tidied up the output within the SQL  editor in the Caché Portal when I tested this, displaying a date rather than a timestamp.  You also might need to change the 14 day test to 15 days.  I think it works for future admissions as well, if that scenario could occur.

Comment: Thank you @imagine that! This will work for sure!